# Question about convergence in probability where random variables depend on another parameter in two different ways

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables, law-of-large-numbers

I am given a sequence of random vectors $\theta_N \in \Theta$ such that $\theta_N \xrightarrow{p} \theta$. I want to show that a $f(x, \theta)$, a continuous scalar-valued function of $\theta$ and $x \in \mathcal{X} \subset \mathbb{R}^D$, satisfies
$$
\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N f(x_i, \theta_N) \xrightarrow{p} \mathbb{E}_{x \sim p(x)} \left [ f(x, \theta) \right ],
$$
where $x_i \sim p(x)$ are i.i.d samples. I know that since $f$ is continuous, we have that
$$
f(x, \theta_N) \xrightarrow{p} f(x, \theta)
$$
for any $x$. So for any finite $N'$, we have that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{N'} f(x_i, \theta_N) \xrightarrow{p} \sum_{i=1}^{N'} f(x_i, \theta).
$$
I would like take the limit as $N' \to \infty$ in the equation above and invoke the weak law of large numbers, but I am unsure if this a valid way to derive the desired result. Any advice or reading recommendations would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Is $\theta_n$ supposed to be independent of $(x_i)$?

Comment: Sorry - should have explained this - $\theta_N$ is an estimate of $\theta$ from the i.i.d samples $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^N$, which we can assume satisfies $\theta_N \xrightarrow{p} \theta$ as $N \to \infty$.